# Navigating folders in a wxWidgets application

Tags: c++, path, filesystems, wxwidgets

I need to navigate between folders in my wx app. I was using the std::filesystem::path, which was pretty handy. Using overloaded operators like + and \ was very good and practical, but the constant conversion to std::string and wxString was verbose.

So, is there a way to do something similar in wxWidgets? In my app, I was using a wxString like that:

```
wxString path = SomeOtherWxStringPath + "\\\\" + "image.png";
```

but this doesn't seem right.
What do you suggest, as my application would be deployed in Windows and Linux.

Comment: I think what you are looking for is: https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.2/classwx_file_name.html#ad6f9ae274e12729fc5689128ea94d16e .

Comment: I have tried to use this, but how? Let's say I want to acess the images folder in the rootAplication path. How do I do that? Like this? wxString path = rootAppPath + "images"; ?

Comment: @NeoFahrenheit, take a look at https://docs.wxwidgets.org/3.2/classwx_standard_paths.html

Comment: @NeoFahrenheit, basically you don't need to navigate anything. You just need to place the file in the folder where executable is and call one of the static methods of the class I referenced.

Comment: If it is in the rootApplication path then you also need the link Igor sent.

Answer (score 0):

My recommendation would be to use `std::fs` and either `utf8_string()` or `ToStdWstring()` for simple conversion from `wxString` to `std::[w]string` respectively (the conversion in the other direction is implicit by default).

But there is also [wxFileName](https://docs.wxwidgets.org/latest/classwx_file_name.html) in wxWidgets if you really want to use it.

Comment: I guess that's the way. Thank you.

Comment: @NeoFahrenheit It is best if your code is as standard C++ compliant as possible. Also I assume in the near future some of the utilities wxWidgets has been providing (because they were nonexistent in C++) might be discontinued as C++ libraries are getting richer by each version.